# C# - how to marshal an array of LPWSTR?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, marshalling

I am trying to marshal a c++ struct that looks like the following:

```
typedef struct _SOME_STRUCT
{
     DWORD count;
     LPWSTR *items;
}
```

"items" is an array of LPWSTR's (the exact number is indicated by "count"). In C# I am representing the struct as:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SOME_STRUCT
{    
     internal uint count;
     internal IntPtr items;
}
```

Then in my code I am doing something like this (where mystruct is of type SOME_STRUCT):

```
if (mystruct.count > 0)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mystruct.count; x++)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(mystruct.items.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size * x);
        string item = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr));
    }
}
```

The count is correct, but the string item is coming out garbled. I'm sure I must be doing something daft as i've had this work before with arrays of other types...just not LPWSTR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LPWSTR is a 'wide' string, i.e., Unicode. [PtrToStringUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringuni.aspx) will probably work better for you.

Also, IntPtr does have the `+` operator overloaded, you should be able to do `IntPtr ptr = mystruct.items + (IntPtr.Size * x)`